# Появление необходимого рабочего пространства при выборе Item у навигационного контрола

Tags: c#, devexpress, wpf

Приветствую! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать такое дело! Необходимо разделить окно приложения на две части, то  есть, например, элементом Grid поделить на две колонки. В левой части навигационный контрол `NavBarControl ( devexpress)`, а вот в правой колонке должны располагаться рабочее пространство, на котором тоже будут уже предустановленные какие-то элементы управления. То есть при выборе `Item` у `NavBarControl` справа меняются`workspaces`?

Где-то эти готовые workspaces уже должны находиться (в папке  Layout, например). Как они будут извлекаться принеобходимости.

Может укажите на подобный пример ссылкой?

Answer (score 1):

Все такое есть в MVVM.. конкретно можно посмотреть в сторону Prism, [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176851/) по русски и есть ссылки на оф.доки

Comment: @gost, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Утверждение основано на прочтении перевода указанного в ссылке выше и документации. Там есть и примеры и описание. Более развернуто чем там у меня ответить не получиться. Можно, конечно, и проще используя   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MyViewModel}">    <view:MyView></view:MyView></DataTemplate>, но на мой взгляд Prism интересней.